# Can't add index via C# to RavenDB database

Tags: c#, nosql, ravendb

I'm trying to create a simple index, which includes two fields from my document: TraceRowID, LoadDate.

So I've created the following class:

```
using Model;
using Raven.Abstractions.Indexing;
using Raven.Client.Indexes;
using Raven.Client.Linq;
using Raven.Client.Document;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Indexes
{
    public class IDLoadDateIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ServiceTrace>
    {
        public IDLoadDateIndex()
        {
            Map = serviceTrace => from st in serviceTrace
                                  select new { ID = st.TraceRowID, LoadDate = st.LoadDate };
        }
    }
}
```

My model is "ServiceTrace":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Model
{
    public class ServiceTrace
    {
        public int TraceRowID { get; set; }
        public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
        public string FullExceptionText { get; set; }
        public string LoadDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And there goes my DAL:

```
using Indexes;
using Raven.Client.Indexes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class DbConnection
    {
        private readonly static DbConnection instance = new DbConnection();
        private Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore documentStore;

        static DbConnection()
        {
        }

        private DbConnection()
        {
            this.documentStore = new Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore { Url = "http://btadmins:8080/" };            
            this.documentStore.Initialize();
            IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(IDLoadDateIndex).Assembly, this.documentStore);
        }

        public static DbConnection Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return instance;
            }
        }

        public Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore DocumentStore
        {
            get
            {
                return documentStore;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, when stepping over on debug mode on the "CreateIndexes" line, it is done succesfully. BUT I can't see any indexes added on the RavenDB management studio silverlight app.
What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking in a named database in the studio?  By not naming a specific database here, you are creating the index in Raven's system database.

Comment: I'm pressing "Indexes" on the top bar menu, and there is only the default: "Raven/DocumentsByEntityName" index

Comment: @ohadinho And in the upper-right corner, do you see `Databases> <system>` or something else?  See [the docs](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/studio/multi-database)

Comment: I see Databases > <MyDatabaseName>

Comment: You right, found it under Databases > <system>. So I should create it under my database and change my code.. but why when I click on the index I see nothing in the Query textbox ?

Comment: @ohadinho - In your code, set `DefaultDatabase = "MyDatabase"` right after the existing `Url` setting you have now.

Comment: yes I will, but still why when I click on the index (when deployed to the system database) on the studio I can't see the query ?